# if you change a s3 bucket and you are using CloudFront will it re-distriboute the file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Amazon S3 bucket with some files in it - I have used CloudFront to distribute it.
Now after the CloudFront is live I need to add an additional file to the bucket.  Will CloudFront find the new file?  Will it automatically distribute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a while - like 15 minutes - but CloudFront will notice changes in the S3 bucket and it will distribute those changes across the content distribution network.